# do you know any manual which explains how can I update the component called remository? I'm in joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla

I just updated my joomla from 1.0.12 to 1.5 but the component remository doesn't appear in my components in joomla 1.5. I have readed in internet that I have to update remository but **I don't know how keep my documents in the new version of remository that is 3.53**
Thanks so much

Comment: http://remository.com/forum/func,view/id,13245/catid,24/

Comment: If you found a solution for your own question, write an answer to it and select it as accepted or - alternatively - delete the question altogether. Otherwise, if you only post your answer in the comments, SO won't display your question as "solved". Cheers! :)

Comment: +1'd ! ;) [need to write some more to get the comment accepted]

Comment: @mac: The minimum character limit in comments is there to encourage you to write useful content, not to fill your comment with meaningless padding.

Comment: @Tomalak - Then this is the proof the system doesn't work then. My goal was to show to a new user how following community conventions on SO is meritorious. To achieve that, "+1, thanks" would have sufficed, but the fact SO wouldn't accept my comment forced me to put "meaningless padding" and increase noise. Poor design choice by SO. A better approach would have been to display a notice like the one that invites you to use the chat when a comment thread is getting long but let users free to decide. Two decades of sites with compulsory registration should have taught something, after all... :(

Comment: @mac: The system does work, but your interpretation of it has not worked! The "+1'd" is not neccessary, as the post's vote count is clearly displayed alongside it. One use case for the comment length limit is to stop this pointless repetition of information; don't blame the system for your subversive use of it! :)

Comment: @mac: (And, FWIW, users are _not_ "free to decide". If you ignore the notice and carry on discussion in a comment thread (oops, like this one) then moderators come along and, rightly, remove it.)

Comment: @Tomalak - I got what you mean and I understand why a message with "+1, thanks" is normally redundant. :) I think in this particular context (where the OP replied to my original message) it was worth giving an explicit feedback, and the fact the system would like to impede me to do so by counting chars is simply... well each of us might have different opinions... but since users are not a Turing machines, it doesn't work the way is intended! :) That said, be sure that after almost two years on SO I might have left 2 or 3 such messages in total. No spamming! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution

http://remository.com/forum/func,view/id,13245/catid,24/